# Angular 2: Deleting recursively instantiated components somehow creates new component instances

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-components

As the title indicates, I have a recursively instantiated group of components. The components are based off of a tree-like data model called Item and are instantiated in nested lists by recursively calling a template and passing my model's nested arrays as @Input() values. While this works fine, the issue is that manipulating the data (which is stored in list.service.ts) that defines how many times this template is instantiated causes certain errors. I have two buttons attached to two functions. One deletes a specific item and shifts the remaining items upwards in the item tree. This works fine. The other button is supposed to delete all items in a given item's item array, effectively deleting its child items. Interestingly, the "delete and shift" function only works correctly if I use a Subject and Subscription for my service and component. While the "delete children" function appears to only work correctly if I do not use a subscription. Instead, it seems to destroy the component instance of the component instance on which I clicked "delete children" (this should not happen as I am not deleting this item, merely it's items array), and then rebuild the nested components from the root component.

For example, if I had the following nested item arrays as rendered by my components in the DOM:

- item 1

  - item 2

    - item 3

      - item 4

and I clicked the Delete Children button on item 3, I would expect onDestroy to be called for item 4, leaving items 1, 2, and 3 untouched, however what it ultimately ends up looking like is this:

- item 1

  - item 1

    - item 2

      - item 3

What I would hope to ask anyone who is more knowledgeable of Angular 2's lifecycle hooks than I am is 1) Why does the subscription stop the delete children function from working correctly, 2) why does the item tree get rebuilt from the root node whenever I click the Delete Children button, and 3) how do I go about changing my code to fix this problem?

**item.model.ts**

```
export class Item{
  constructor(public id: number, public details: string, public date: Date, public items?: Item[]){}
}
```

**item-list.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ul>
      <li> {{item.details}}
        <br>
        <button (click)="onDelete(item.id)">Delete</button>
        <button (click)="onDeleteChildren(item.id)">
          Delete Children</button>
         <app-item-list [items]="item.items" *ngIf="item.items">
         </app-item-list>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**item-list.component.ts**

```
  @Input() items: Item[] = [];
  listSubscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private list: ListService) {
    this.items = this.list.getItems();
    console.log('constructor called');
    this.listSubscription = this.list.listUpdated.subscribe(
      (items: Item[]) => {
        this.items = items;
      }
    );
  }

  onDelete(index: number) {
    this.list.deleteItemAndShiftChildren(index);
  }

  onDeleteChildren(index: number) {
    this.list.deleteChildItems(index);   
  }
```

**list.service.ts**

```
  deleteChildItems(index: number) {
    this.recursiveChildDelete(this.items, index);
    this.listUpdated.next(this.items.slice());
  }

  deleteItemAndShiftChildren(index: number) {
    this.recursiveChildShift(this.items, this.items[0], index);
    this.listUpdated.next(this.items.slice());
  }

  recursiveChildDelete(items: Item[], index: number) {
    items.forEach( element => {
      if (element.id === index) {
        if(element.items){
          element.items = [];
        }
      } else if (element.items) {
        this.recursiveChildDelete(element.items, index);
      }
    });
  }

  recursiveChildShift(items: Item[], oldItem: Item, index: number) {
    items.forEach( element => {
      // if the id of the element to be deleted is found
      if (element.id === index) {
      //if the deleted element is the root node
        if(oldItem==element){
          if(element.items){
            this.items = element.items;
            return;
          } else {
            this.items = [];
            return;
          }
        }
        oldItem.items = element.items;
        return;
      } else if (element.items) {
        oldItem = element;
        this.recursiveChildShift(element.items, oldItem, index);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Your code is really hard to get running. There are some elements missing. Do you see any chance providing the whole project via Dropbox or so?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there were two keys to solving this problem:

1) The sample data I was using was not made correctly. I had the same id values for two items in my items array, which was giving me a strange error on specific operations. So I fixed that.

2) I created a root component that held a subscription to the array in my service, which passed its value to a child component that recursively generated the list. This way I only had one place, the root, that was receiving updates from the service Subject, and building the array from that root component. The way I was initially doing it, I had every component that was a part of the component tree subscribing to a Subject in my service, which was wrong.